# php foreach loop behavior

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I am attempting to run a mysql query for every item in the foreach loop.

In this example the array `$subChild` has the IDs `1` and `2` in it.
When I attempt to run the following code, it only outputs the information relative to ID `1` once.

Array var_dump: `array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) }`

MySQL Table:

```
sectionID | sectionName | sectionPerms
---------------------------------------
1         | Demo Sub    | 1
2         | Demo Sub 2  | 1
```

Heres my code:

```
foreach($subChild as $sub) {
  $getSub = $con->prepare("SELECT sectionID,sectionName FROM sections WHERE sectionID=? AND sectionPerms=1");
  $getSub->bind_param("i", $sub);
  $getSub->execute();
  $getSub->store_result();
  $getSub->bind_result($sectionID,$sectionName);
  while($getSub->fetch()) {
  ?>
<td><a href="./view.php?t=cat&id=<?php echo $sectionID; ?>"><?php echo $sectionName; ?></a></td>
  <?php
  };
  $getSub->close();
};
```

The output for this code is simply something similar to:

```
<td><a href="./view.php?t=cat&id=1">Sub Section 1</a></td>
```

It doesn't even repeat it twice.

How would I go about fixing this issue so that the foreach loop will work for **every item in the array**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing the connection *after* your loop (and, for that matter, you can prepare the query before the loop):

```
$getSub = $con->prepare("SELECT `sectionID`, `sectionName` FROM `sections` WHERE `sectionID`=? AND `sectionPerms`=1");

foreach($subChild as $sub) {
    $getSub->execute(array($sub));
    $data = $getSub->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "<td><a href='./view.php?t=cat&id={$data["sectionID"]}'>{$data["sectionName"]}</a></td>";
};

$getSub->close();
```

Comment: Hi, I have applied your recommended changes and it still seems to only return a single sub section. Strange...

Comment: When you use `var_dump($subChild)`, what do you see?

Comment: `array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) }`

Comment: @Daimos if you close the connection each iteration of the loop without reopening it, then maybe that's the reason why the loop doesn't run more than once. Just a consideration, no need to be an ass

Comment: You have closed connection after the loop

Comment: @Daimos yes, instead of during, which is what the code in the OP question was. Stop trying to find issues with the answers and start trying to find answers to the questions!

Comment: @Daimos, if you're not here to help - please leave.

Comment: Okay, using `store_result` and `bind_result` didn't seem to be helping. Also, it seemed you were binding to "i", which didn't appear in the query. I used `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to put the data from the query result into `$data`, and echo that out instead. Let me know if it works!

Comment: @BenPearlKahan, it's okay. I ended Up figuring it out, thanks for your efforts :D

Comment: @FileParts what was the issue?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan, a dumb mistake on my half, I have tables `sections` and `subsections` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `;` in your code

```
foreach($subChild as $sub) {
  $getSub = $con->prepare("SELECT sectionID,sectionName FROM sections WHERE sectionID=? AND sectionPerms=1");
  $getSub->bind_param("i", $sub);
  $getSub->execute();
  $getSub->store_result();
  $getSub->bind_result($sectionID,$sectionName);
  while($getSub->fetch()) {
  ?>
<td><a href="./view.php?t=cat&id=<?php echo $sectionID; ?>"><?php echo $sectionName; ?></a></td>
  <?php
  }
  $getSub->close();
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for the response. I have removed the `;` from the places where you have, it still seems to only output 1 sub section rather than 2

Comment: Why advising to remove `;`? How can this be relevant?